# Can we map All Entities in single mappings file in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have many Model Entities like

```
class Employee {

   private Integer id;

   private String name;  

}


class Address {

   private Integer id;

   private String address;  

}
```

and many more..

Can we map all Entities together in **single hbm xml** mapping file?
I know it might not be good practice. but Still can we do it? If yes then how ?

Comment: Do you mean for all entities you want to use Single `SomeName.hbm.xml` file?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is possible to use a single mapping file.

Something like this:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Employee" table="employee">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id"/>
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="name"/>
        </property>
    </class>

    <class name="Address" table="address">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id"/>
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="address" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="address"></column>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Do we need to do any extra configuration?

Comment: No need of extra configuration

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this, the dtd (http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd) allows multiple class elements in `hibernate-mapping`:

```
<!ELEMENT hibernate-mapping (
    ...
    (class|subclass|joined-subclass|union-subclass)*,
    ...
)>
```

Even the documentation (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-declaration, second code block) maps as an example a `Cat` and a `Dog` class in the same file.